# Issue when copying (dragging down) a formula referencing Pivot Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table(rather large) with every other row being referenced in a `COUNTIF()` to get a count of a different services available.
the pivot data looks like this:

```
  A            B           C        D         E           F
1 Service A    Cost    Service B   Cost    Service C    Cost
2 234          3.50        0       3.50       42         5.00
3 0            3.50        12      3.50       0          5.00
4 ...
```

My formula is:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,>0),COUNTIF(C2,>0),COUNTIF(E2,>0))
```

The formula works in the first row that I typed it in, but if I drag the formula down, nothing updates. The formula changes to A3,A4,A5, etc but the value the formula returns is incorrect. Another wierd thing is that if I click into the formula box and click out, it will update and display the correct value....

Any idea why it won't give me the correct values?

Answer (score 1):

manual calculations were turned on.

Tools > Options > Calculations

hope that helps anyone else with the same issue!